# Как можно сделать сайт на C++?

Tags: c++, веб-программирование

Понимаю, что для таких целей есть специальные языки, но я не хочу к ним прикасаться по личным причинам. Сайт не визитка. Есть отдельная программа наподобие бота, которая выступает сервером в некоторой игре, и там я пишу все на C++, но хочу вынести интерфейс на сайт, если можно так сказать, ну, в общем, подобное уже делалось на php, но мне не достаточно тех функций, что уже там сделаны, и просто as is не получится, а нужно ещё свои добавлять, а не зная php и не имея пока желания его знать, не совсем удачная идея. Так вот, какие есть, по вашему, хорошие библиотеки для этого или как лучше поступить(в пределах С++)?

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?q=c%2B%2B%20web%20application%20framework&q

что до конкретной ситуации, то я бы посоветовал просто вынести в публичный доступ (в пределах сервера) весь интерфейс игрового сервера и тянуть его из веб-приложения хоть посредством командной строки.

Comment: @Etki, а что насчет Wt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Гуглите по словам "cgi c++", найдете [такое](http://www.gnu.org/software/cgicc/) и многое другое.

Я бы не рекомендовал писать все на плюсах. Берите апач/nginx, основной сайт пишите на php/perl/python/ - любом другом любимом языке. А вот критичные части - на плюсах. Например, получение json с результатами поиска.